# How to remove notification icon from theme Jepson in Experience Builder?

Tags: community, partner-communities, experience-builder-page

Can't find how to hide the notif icon in Jespn :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to remove the notification icon from the compact header's layout. Tried this in my org and it works.

[image]

Clickpath: Setup> Digital Experiences> Your site's Builder> Click Compact Header> Layout> Uncheck the "Show Notifications" checkbox